# Facing MemoryError in Python

Tags: python, memory, error-messages

I wrote a program to find prime factors of a number.
When I give a large number(600851475143) as input, `MemoryError` pops up.
Below is the code:

```
def fact(a):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if a%i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors 

num = raw_input(">>  ")
#600851475143
a = b = []
a = fact(long(num))    
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    b = fact(a[i])
    if len(b) <= 2:
        print a[i]
```

From browsing I came to know that Python makes use of Computer memory - RAM. I am using Python in Unbuntu without changing its configuration. Should I change anythig to work on 64-bit machine.
Or should I use any additional function(s) to get around this error

Comment: Your basic issue is that your algorithm is likely using too much memory.  If you are using python 2, then `range(1, a+1)` is attempting to create a list with 600851475143 elements.  This is probably not what you want as each element will be an integer and each integer takes 4 bytes.  (Also, this question isn't appropriate for Programmers as you really need a code review and to understand in particular how python works.)

Comment: (You probably want `xrange`, which is a generator that returns elements to the `for` loop as needed.  That may not be the only issue you are having, though.)

Comment: Your list is 2.2TB big. Switching to a 64 bit machine will not help. You need to install more than 2TB of RAM (which to be fair will require a 64 bit OS to use). Or re-think your algorithm.

Comment: In addition to memory issues (just because no others have pointed out so far), there are some more efficient algorithms for calculating the list of factors of a number, or to decide whether a number is prime, or to generate a list of prime numbers. While most people talk about [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), there is also the related concept of [space complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to measure the memory used by your program, and you may be able increase  per-user limits or something.

However, you don't need to allocate that memory in the first place, since you can just generate the sequence without storing it all:

```
def fact(a):
    "just return a generator for the sequence you want"
    return (i for i in xrange(1,a+1) if a % i == 0)
```

Note that you can also iterate directly over sequences without needing to index them repeatedly:

```
for b in fact(long(num)):
    print b
```

Comment: The list in the question is 2.2TB big, I doubt raising resource limits will help :-D

Comment: Well, maybe the OP can wait until 2035, when 8TB SIMMS are available.